# Check the render method of `InputOption`

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

Trying to render the component but getting an error message.

The below code runs correctly

```
function InputOption(Icon, title, color) {
    return(  <div className='inputOption'>
        </div>
  )
}

export default InputOption
```

As soon as I start calling the props it flags an error.

```
function InputOption(Icon, title, color) {
    return( <div className='inputOption'>
        <Icon style={{color : color}}/>
        </div>
   )
}

export default InputOption
```

Reading online it might be something to do with Import/ Export but cant get my head around it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Anes 'Check the render method of 'InputOption'

Comment: @Anes Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 0):

Use object destructuring to get the props :)

By default, a component gets one prop.
eg:
`function InputOption(props){...}`

> This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single
> “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and
> returns a React element. We call such components “function components”
> because they are literally JavaScript functions.

```
function InputOption({Icon, title, color}){...}
```

By destructuring, you're can get all the "attributes" of the props object.

---

**EDIT**

Please provide more information (how do you actually call the InputOption component and about the Icon component)

[Check this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-moser-uxjnr)

Comment: Please provide more information about the Icon component